# Laravel eloquent - making query with optional value key parameters with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query with optional parameters array, that could look something like this:

```
array:3 [
  "parent" => "prosjektsamarbeidets"
  "category" => "article"
  "slug" => "prosjektsamarbeidets-verdi"
]
```

It will always have a slug parameter but other parameters are optional in the array.
With this arguments I need to make a query in the Model `Content`, where the relationship for the `category` which refers in this case to the model `Taxonomy` is set up like this:

```
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\ContentTaxonomy', 'taggable');
}
```

And the `parent` key value if it exists is the name of the record from the content table, which has this columns:

```
id | cms_id | title | slug | excerpt | body | parent_id
```

How can I do such a query, after I get the `content` by `slug`?

```
$post = Content::where('slug',$arguments['slug'])->get();

if (array_key_exists('parent', $arguments)) {
      //do further query by parent name
}

if (array_key_exists('category', $arguments)) {
      //do further query by category
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
public function taxonomies()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\ContentTaxonomy', 'taggable')->withPivot('additional_attribute', 'additional_attribute');;
}
```

Then, you can access those variables by doing so:

```
foreach ($shop->taxonomies as $taxonomy)
{
    echo $taxonomy->pivot->additional_attribute;
}
```

Or you meant:

```
$post = Content::taxonomies()->where('slug',$arguments['slug'])->get();
```

Let me know if that what you meant?